# Weblogic WLST get deployments status

Tags: weblogic12c, wlst

I am trying to get deployments status from Weblogic Scripting tool. By deployments I mean list of deployments shown in Weblogic server administration console - Domain structure - Deployments

I found that using:

```
cd ('AppDeployments')
print cmo.getAppDeployments()
```

I can get state of "some" app deployments (I found names of these apps in config.xml), but those are not from Weblogic server administration console. Can anybody suggest where I can get that list and it's current state ?

Comment: here there is a WLST script for listing apps & shared libs https://blogs.oracle.com/practicalbpm/wlst-scripting-to-get-weblogic-libraries-and-deployed-applications

Answer (score 4):

My script for listing apps :

```
connect('weblogic','welcome1','t3://127.0.0.1:7001')
cd('AppDeployments')
deplymentsList=cmo.getAppDeployments()

for app in deplymentsList:
      domainConfig()
      cd ('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets')
      mytargets = ls(returnMap='true')
      domainRuntime()
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      for targetinst in mytargets:
            curstate4=cmo.getCurrentState(app.getName(),targetinst)
            print '----', app.getApplicationName(), ' | ', app.getVersionIdentifier(), ' | ', app.getModuleType(), ' | ',  targetinst, ' | ', curstate4, ' | ', app.getSecurityDDModel(), ' | ', app.getAbsoluteSourcePath()
```

More scripts can be found at: https://github.com/devwebcl/wls_contraption/tree/master/wlst